# Python: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am using regex to calculate the value of a string that contains real numbers and addition, such as '3.4+5.2'. This is the code:

```
import re

a = str(raw_input())

counter = a.count('+')
for i in range(counter):
    add = re.match('([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\+([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', a)
    temp = float(add.groups()[0]) + float(add.groups()[1])
    a = re.sub('([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\+([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', str(temp), a)
print a
```

It works fine for:

```
>>> a = '3+4'
'7.0'
>>> a = '3+4+5'
'12.0'
```

But, when I try to add more than twice:

```
>>> a = '3+4+5+6'
7.07.0
    temp = float(add.groups()[0]) + float(add.groups()[1])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Why does this error appear, how can it be fixed?

Comment: `re.match` finds nothing, so there's no group.

Comment: `re.match` returns `None` if there's no match. Trying to access `groups` raises `AttributeError`. (`None.groups(...)`)

Comment: @timgeb I understand what the error means, but there is something to be found.. and it works in the first two examples.

Comment: Ah...why don't just `a.split('+')`, without regex?

Comment: @janedoe, After the first iteration, `a` become `7.07.0` which does not have `+` -> no match.

Comment: @falsetru ohh, I understand.. How can I fix that?

Comment: @janedoe, I posted an answer. Check it out.

Comment: I see you have the solution with a `re.sub(,,,)` with count. However, `([+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))\+([+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))` might be a better regex, fractions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) returns `None` if there's no match. Trying to access `groups` raises `AttributeError`. (`None.groups(...)`)

After the first iteration, `a` become `7.07.0` which does not have `+`. The reason is `re.sub` replace all matches, not only the first match.

To make it replace only the first occurence, you need to specify `count`:

```
a = re.sub('([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\+([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', str(temp), a, count=1)
```

---

As Kevin Guan commented, using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) will be better; easy to read, simple:

```
>>> '3+4+5+6'.split('+')
['3', '4', '5', '6']
>>> map(float, '3+4+5+6'.split('+'))
[3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
>>> sum(map(float, '3+4+5+6'.split('+')))
18.0
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for me, because I will add other operators later. I still don't understand how my code works for '3+4+5' and not for '3+4+5+6'. The second one should be transformed into '7.0+5+6', then to '12.0+6' and then to '18.0'. Why is that not happening?

Comment: @janedoe, Because there are two matches in `3+4+5+6`. `re.sub` without `count` argument, replaces them all. I updated the answer to mention it.

Comment: Could you show me how to do this using regex, as I tried?

Comment: @janedoe, I updated the answer to include it. Please reload this page if you see old answer.

Comment: @falsetru: No problem :)

Comment: @janedoe: Well, I don't think use regex in this case is correct. However the regex will be very ugly, complex, unreadable. Since Python support basic math, I'd recommend use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) like `ast.literal_eval('3+4+5+6')`.

Comment: @KevinGuan, `ast.literal_eval` works only with literals: `ast.literal_eval('3')` works, but `ast.literal_eval('3+4+5+6')` does not.

Comment: @falsetru: Well, just tested, it depends. On Python 2, it raise `ValueError: malformed string`. On Python 3, it gives `18` as the expect.

Comment: @KevinGuan, This question is tagged `python-2.7`

Comment: Ah, fine. However don't know that it doesn't work on Python 2 before.